# How to profile people using clustering

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, data-analysis, clustering, data-mining

I have a data of customers and i want to split them to segment (profiling).
The columns of the data are Amount-Spending, Amount-Bonus, Age, Churn-or-Not. 
So i clustered my data with k-means. to 3 clusters. 
Now, how can i show that the first column of the data ('Amount-Spending') is more close to cluster number 1 for example. 
So i can say that cluster number 1 are people that usually spend a lot of money and not just, customer number 5 is in cluster 1.

Comment: You can try and measure correllation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are in danger to misuse Cluster Analysis, which is a technique to **discover** structure in data and not to describe a structure that one just assumes to exist. To see what I mean, ask yourself the following questions for example:

1. Why are you clustering into 3 groups? Not 4 or 9?
2. When plotting the data (luckily there are 3 attributes only), do you see any groups? How many? How can these groups roughly be described using the values of the attributes?
3. KMeans uses the Euklidean distance as a measure of similarity of samples. Is this the appropriate measure in your case?

Comment: Very good arguments. +1